# Software to find free street car parking in UK

Tags: web-apps

Is there any software to find free street car parking in uk

I know softwares that shows PARKING or Free PARKING but non shows which streets are free of charge to park in different councils in UK.

I am more interested in UK.

Comment: Are you sure you want a web app? Not an Android app for instance? Must the software be free?